# Solana wallet adapter issues

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, react

I found this very annoying with solana wallet adapter issue with webpack 5 and react scripts version > 5

A smooth solution is to clone this repo and use create-react-app-started which is inside packages and migrate all your code here

Here's the repo
https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter/create-react-app-starter

Comment: This isn't a question. What was the issue you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smooth solution is to clone this repo and use create-react-app-started which is inside packages and migrate all your code here

Here's the repo https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter/create-react-app-starter